# Why is \textsc not working on this tabularray?

Tags: macros, small-caps, tabularray

I can't figure out why I can't make the title row in this tabularray environment to be small caps (seems to happen as soon as I add the `row{2} = {font = \bfseries, cmd = \textrm},`, but I can't override it by adding `row{1} = {cmd = \textsc},`.

I just **KNOW** I am doing something stupid...especially because I actually can't get this to compile properly without including the `pythontex` package...which makes no sense to me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[margin = 0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
% timeperiod calculations
\begin{tblr}[T]{
  colspec = {Q[c,m] *{4}{Q[c,m,$]}},
  column{1} = {2-Z}{font = \bfseries},
  row{odd} = {azure9},
  row{2} = {font = \bfseries, cmd = \textrm},
  hline{1,Z} = {2pt},
}
% header
\SetCell[c=5]{c} \textsc{Why am I not Small Caps?} \\
\hline
 &
  who &
    cares &
      not &
        me \\
tab &
  \mathrm{10\ \frac{units}{time}} &
    \mathrm{7\ units} &
      \mathrm{1\ unit \cdot 2\ units} &
        \mathrm{10\ unit^2} \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Edit: To clarify, I am aware there is no bold small caps in the Computer Modern fonts. Which is why I am trying not to apply the bold to the first row.

As I understand it, I should be making the first column bold from the second row on and the second row entirely bold. I do not understand where I would be applying bold to my header.

Using `\normalfont \textsc{Why am I not Small Caps?}` makes it display properly; I just don't understand *why*.

Edit #2:
So @Clara's comment does work; but I think maybe I still need to understand what is going on. Because, I think it's probably the same error I am running into elsewhere when I am trying to do these complex formatting preambles.

Answer (score 5):

This is unrelated to the table or pythontex.

latex warns

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/bx/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/bx/n' instead on input line 32.
```

That is, there is no bold computer modern small caps so it substitutes normal bold.

You could use the ec fonts by adding

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

[image]

Comment: But why is bold being applied to those cells? From what I see, I am making column 1 bold from the second row on and the second row completely bold...this is the first row...I'm sorry, I can tell it's something stupid

Comment: @user er that's a reasonable question:-) I'll look tomorrow unless someone in a more reasonable timezone has answered by then.

Comment: @user You should use `cell{2-Z}{1}={font=\bfseries},` not `column{1}={2-Z}{font=\bfseries},`.

Comment: @Clara thanks...

Answer (score 3):

As @DavidCarlisle points out in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679392/5001), the Computer Modern text font family doesn't include the bold/smallcaps combination.

The remedy? Use a font that does provide the needed weight/shape combination. The `newtxtext` and `newpxtext` packages, which provide Times Roman and Palatino clones, respectively, are examples of font packages thatfeature this combination.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % amsmath is loaded automatically by mathtools
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[margin = 0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % or: \usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

\begin{document}
% timeperiod calculations
\begin{tblr}[T]{
  colspec = {Q[c,m] *{4}{Q[c,m,$]}},
  column{1} = {2-Z}{font = \bfseries},
  row{odd} = {azure9},
  row{2} = {font = \bfseries, cmd = \textrm},
  hline{1,Z} = {2pt},
}
% header
\SetCell[c=5]{c} \textsc{Why am I not Small Caps?} \\
\hline
 &
  who &
    cares &
      not &
        me \\
tab &
  \mathrm{10\ \frac{units}{time}} &
    \mathrm{7\ units} &
      \mathrm{1\ unit \cdot 2\ units} &
        \mathrm{10\ unit^2} \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But why would that cell (or any of those cells) be bold? I make the first column bold from rows 2 on and the second row completely bold...nothing else is bold...I don't understand it.

Comment: @user - Has Clara's comment below [David Carlisle's posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/679392/5001) managed to answer your question?